# How to create a thread that waits for a boolean variable to become true?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a function that needs to be called once a boolean variable is true. I tried using a while loop in a thread but it doesn't work. Here is what I've tried:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    while (true) {
         if (conditions == true) { 
             System.out.println("second");
             break;
         }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean condition = false;
    (new Thread(new MyRunnable())).start();
    System.out.println("first\n");
    // set conndition to true
    condition = true;

    }

}
```

The result shoud be:

```
first
second
```

Comment: wrong use `Runnable#Thread` and to manage loop by using real boolean variable   `while (canRun) {` instead of endless `while (true) {`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Do not busy-wait** for such conditions. Use a blocking idiom. For your simple case you would get away with a `new CountDownLatch(1)`. First, here's your code, but fixed to compile and run the way you expect:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  volatile boolean condition = false;

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      if (condition) {
        System.out.println("second");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
    new Thread(r).start();
    System.out.println("first\n");
    r.condition = true;
  }
}
```

For comparison, a program with a `CountDownLatch`:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  public void run() {
    try { latch.await(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("second");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
    new Thread(r).start();
    System.out.println("first\n");
    r.latch.countDown();
  }
}
```

To truly notice the difference, add a `Thread.sleep(20000)` after `println("first")` and **hear** the difference in the sound of your computer's fan working hard to dissipate the energy the first program is wasting.

Comment: @Igor - It will use CPU unnecessarily.

Comment: Wasting CPU is a very serious problem not just in terms of performance. It wastes something even more tangible: **energy**. Even if you don't care about electricity bills or the environment, **everybody** cares about the battery life of their device.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a place for java's wait notify construct.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

  public run() {
    synchronized(this) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
    System.out.println("second");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable r = new MyRunnable();    
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    System.out.println("first\n");
    synchronized (r) {
      r.notify();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Neat. But, I can't use it in my specific example. I only posted a SSCCE. In my code I set the condition to true in another method. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's possible that you'll never see "second" printed in this case. The main thread could send `notify()` before the `run()` started. Then `wait()` ends up waiting endless as there's no one to notify it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way. Instead, you can use `Object`'s built in `notify()` and `wait()` methods like so:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

private final Object condition;

public MyRunnable(Object condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

public void run() {
    condition.wait();
    System.out.println("second");
}

public void go(String args[]) {
        Object condition = new Object();
        (new Thread(new MyRunnable(condition))).start();
        System.out.println("first\n");
        // set conndition to true
        condition.notify();
    }
}
```

If you want fancier notification schemes, you can also look in `java.util.concurrent` for more powerful ways of letting threads wait on more interesting conditions. All of these will be much more CPU-efficient than just spinning until a condition is true, and they're less likely to introduce concurrency bugs due to subtleties in Java's memory model.

Comment: Waiting must be done in a loop due to spurious wakeups and you must first acquire a lock on `condition`'s monitor. Then there's the issue of `notify` vs. `notifyAll`... better just forget that this mechanism exists in Java. It served its duty, time to retire.